# Rails installation quirk on digital ocean

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx

I'm trying to set up a droplet on digital ocean to run an existing rails app. I'm using mysql, rails (obviously), and nginx. I get everything installed nicely. I can shut down the machine and all, and see that all the software packages are there. however, when I add a user in the mysql command line (called deploy - same as the user on the droplet), none of the software is available. 
before I make the user, I can do rails -v and get a version, and ruby -v and get a number, but after creating the mysql user, all I get is "ruby can be installed with these packages: ruby, ruby1.8

Why is this? did mysql change my deploy user's rights or something?

Comment: turns out what it triggering this is my logging out of the deploy user and back in. Any ideas what is going on or how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the .bashrc file in such scenarios. It takes care of setting the path. If the droplet is the image of Ubuntu then you need to do '. ~/.bashrc'